# how can i use servlet in jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

```
<body>
  <form action="testServlet.java">
  <TABLE border="0" align="center">
    <TR height="40">
      <TD width="40"><a href="Hoda/testServlet?direction=b"><img
        src=<%=request.getAttribute("imgSrc")%> width="40" height="40" /></a>
      </TD>
  </form>
</body>
```

SERVLET:

```
@WebServlet("/testServlet")
public class testServlet extends HttpServlet {
   String imgSrc = "red.png";

   protected void service(HttpServletRequest reques,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

      String str = request.getParameter("direction");

      if (str.startsWith("b")) {
        imgSrc = "black.png";
      }

      request.setAttribute("imgSrc", imgSrc);
   }
}
```

In my JSP page, I created a cell whose image source I want to get from servlet. I put the link tag to ask servlet for imgSrc, but it does not work . Please show me how to change the imgSrc in JSP page using servlet. I want the JSP to merely show the result, not a dispatch to another page.
    here is my code :

Comment: Define "does not work". You'd have to click the link to request the servlet; are you doing that then forwarding to the same jsp? Doesn't look like it-are you sure you know how servlets and clients interact?

Comment: for me it looks fine. except that the form action is responsible for communication with the servlet, so I'd not expect the image to load until you press a button or something on the form, so the action can take place

Comment: @MoatazElmasry It does? Submitting to a source file, and a link to a servlet that doesn't redirect or forward?

Comment: I'm a newbee in jsp,could u pleas  tell me how to forward req from jsp to servlet?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the Servlet API's RequestDispatcher to forward from the Servlet to the JSP so that the processing occurs on the same request, otherwise the attribute won't be set.  You could probably also use some custom include logic, but typically you'd use the servlet as a "front" and then use the JSP to render the content.  Hopefully this makes sense, you should be able to track the APIs down in the Servlet JavaDoc.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this post may be can help you.

http://ajax911.com/dynamically-display-images-java-servlet-tomcat/